# Reading phantom NFC tags via javax.smartcardio

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

I have an an old NFC reader for the tikitag web service (which was later renamed [touchatag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchatag), and finally abandoned around 2012). Since the website is no longer available, I could no longer find the original tikitag/touchatag drivers. After some searching, I found this NFC reader is a generic ACS ACR122U USB reader, and installed a suitable driver from [here](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122U). My system is Windows 7 (64-bits).

First, I tried the [NFC Tools library](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) for high-level read and write access to NFC tags. I got an error saying an unsupported tag was encountered; although no tag was present on the reader, or even remotely nearby. It seems other developers also encountered the same error with this library, as shown [here](https://code.google.com/p/nfctools/issues/detail?id=12). Note  this tag is detected ad infinitum (so, it does not just disappear after being detected once).

I copied the required low-level code into a separate class (i.e., independent from the NFC Tools library). You can find this code below (similar code can also be found in tutorials):

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;

import org.nfctools.utils.NfcUtils;

public class NdefTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();
        CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

        if (terminal.waitForCardPresent(5000)) {
            Card card = terminal.connect("T=0");
            System.out.println(NfcUtils.convertBinToASCII(card.getATR().getHistoricalBytes()));
        }
    }
}
```

This code detects the exact same "phantom" tag as when using the NFC Tools library. Therefore, this issue seems unrelated to the NFC Tools library (as implied by the library developer in response to the error report). Either I'm missing something, or the issue is either related to the installed driver, the NFC reader hardware, or some unfixed bug in javax.smartcardio (listed in order of likelihood).

I have tried uninstalling the aforementioned driver and letting Windows 7 install a suitable driver on its own (called "Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)"), which results in the same errors as described above. I have not tried another reader, since I only have the one.

(Note: the name of this NFC reader in the Windows device overview is "CCID USB Reader", instead of "ACS ACR122" or something related. Don't know whether this is important, just thought I would mention it.).

Has anyone encountered this issue, and managed to resolve it?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I've tried sending a CLF command to the reader after the simulated tag has been detected; namely, getting the ATS of the connected PICC (p. 11 of the [ACR122U manual](http://www.acs.com.hk/drivers/eng/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf)):

```
TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
List<CardTerminal> terminals = factory.terminals().list();

// (this is the correct terminal)
CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);

if (terminal.waitForCardPresent(5000)) {
    Card card = terminal.connect("*");

    CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();

// (I tried both 0x00 and 0x01 as P1, as well as 0x05 for Le)
    CommandAPDU getAts = new CommandAPDU(0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04);
    ResponseAPDU response = channel.transmit(getAts);

    System.out.println(response.getSW1());
    System.out.println(response.getSW2());
}
```

But I keep getting an error response code (0x63 0x00). Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you encounter is that this version of the ACR122U reader uses PC/SC (CCID) in a somewhat non-standard way.

The "card" that you detect with the PC/SC API is actually either a dummy card simulated by the reader (to allow the PC/SC API to open a connection even if no card is present) or a smartcard chip in the reader's SAM slot (contact card present inside the reader's casing).

In either case, this reader uses PC/SC only as a transport protocol for native commands of the contactless frontend chip used within this reader (NXP PN532). Thus, if you want to use the reader's contactless functionality, you have to use the CLF's native command set. See the [ACR122U API documentation](http://www.acs.com.hk/drivers/eng/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf) or the [libnfc](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Libnfc) implementation for further details.

Comment: Sounds to me like a very non-standard use of the API. It's amazing that this question was answered in about 4 hours, compared to - well - never :)

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Are you saying the Java smartcard API does not support this particular NFC reader? Strange, since this seems to be a relatively popular type of NFC reader.. 

So, by sending these (CLF?) commands from the ACS documentation to the NFC reader, I will be able to access its functionality? At any rate, I'm assuming those commands cannot be sent via Java, since that requires opening a CardChannel to a detected card (and only the simulated or embedded card is ever detected)..

Comment: No, that's not what I was saying. Java Smartcard IO API supports any reader that exposes a PC/SC interface. As the ACR122U is a CCID device, it can be accessed trough PC/SC.

Comment: Now the problem is that PC/SC is used in a (somewhat) non-standard way by using it as a tunnel for proprietary CLF commands. As the reader ALWAYS shows a card-present (either a physical one or a simulated one) you can ALWAYS connect using the Java SC IO API. You do so by just connecting to whatever card the reader shows you it "detected". Then you can tunnel commands to the CLF by sending them over that connection. The CLF commands contain a non-standard CLA byte (0xFF) that tells the reader to unwrap and pass the commands to the CLF instead of passing them to the actual card (if present).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried sending ADPU commands to the NFC reader after the simulated tag was detected; see original post for an update.

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest you stick to using the direct transmit method (see section 6.1) in combination with native PN532 commands (see user manual: http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/141520.pdf)

Comment: I get an error "Unknown error 0x8010002f" whenever I set Le to 0x00 (for any command). I got one of the pseudo APDUs to work (from ACS doc, section 6.1), namely getting the firmware version; the rest all return the error code 63h 00h (get/set PICC op param, etc). Regarding the native PN532 commands; I must admit this document is too low-level for me (not clear how this links to the concrete bytes that need to be sent). I had a look at the available command set (section 7), and they do not seem to correspond to the ones from the ACS documentation.

Comment: Looking at the documentation of CommandAPDU it seems that the last argument is not Le but Ne (i.e. the actual expected length instead of the encoded expected length). Thus, to get Le = 0 you would need to set Ne = 256 (assuming a regular length APDU is constructed): new CommandAPDU(0xFF, 0xCA, p1, 0x00, 256);

Comment: Also in the code I usually use to talk to that reader, I found that I use the constructor without any Ne field:
cmdAPDU = new CommandAPDU(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, command);
With command being a PN532 command. For instance a polling command for all card types: byte[] command = new byte[]{ (byte)0xD4, (byte)0x60, (byte)0xFF, 1, 0x20, 0x23, 0x10, 0x04, 0x11, 0x12 }

Comment: Ok thanks, that worked for me. See answer below for a short summary.

Answer (score 1):

*(all credit goes to Michael Roland; this post is meant as a solution summary)*

Ok Michael, given the example in your last comment, I finally understand what you mean by using the PC/SC protocol for tunneling CLF commands. I tested some of the commands in the PN532 documentation, and they return valid results. (However, the command you gave as an example didn't work and crashed the reader; it had to be reset.)

For instance, to get the firmware version:

```
CommandAPDU commApdu = new CommandAPDU(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    new byte[] { (byte)0xD4, (byte)0x02 });
```

InDataExchange command:

```
CommandAPDU commApdu = new CommandAPDU(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    new byte[] { (byte)0xD4, (byte)0x40, 0x01 });
```

I found the [NFCIP library](https://code.google.com/p/nfcip-java/), which supports sending byte arrays between peers (examples are ACS ACR122 and Nokia 6131) using the InDataExchange command. When reading the PN532 documentation (p. 131), it seems that this command allows reading tags as well. Michael, do you happen to know of any library that handles uses these low-level commands with the goal of **reading (different types of) tags**?

Comment: Hehe, the command I provided has a wait-forever (the 0xFF) in it, so it will only return if the reader detects a card.

Comment: Michael, judging by your latest comments it would seem you have code lying around that is able to read and write various types of tags using this reader ;) Do you care to share some of your knowledge? :)